# Is My Theme Corrupting My Cart Shipping Options?

Tags: magento2, theme

I posted a portion of this issue on Reddit, but after reading through a few posts here regarding issues with free shipping configuration I'm now wondering if the theme layered onto my site is somehow interfering with not only my basic "Free Shipping" mechanism, but the presentation of shipping options in general.

I have "Free Shipping" enabled and set to trigger at $100 USD. It does not appear in the cart when that threshold is passed. I thought Free Shipping was that simple to configure, but perhaps not.

I've also tried configuring a USPS and UPS "Method" as "Free Method" but all that seems to do is set the cost of that method to $0 when the $100 threshold is passed, when it works. It seems that even if UPS Ground is configured as the Free Method within UPS, it still calculates as a $ amount.

If I'm correct in separating the core "Free Shipping" from a carrier-specific "Free Method" does anyone know why the Free Shipping option is not presented in the cart at all?

(If I select the option for Free Shipping to "Show Method if Not Applicable" it does appear in the cart, but ONLY when the cart value is LESS THAN $100 and then of course is not selectable and displays the configured error message.)

Also - Even though it appears that I have USPS set up correctly, all USPS options disappear as the cart value reaches $100. Only UPS is presented.

The behavior seems random or at least difficult to diagnose, to the point that I think something in the environment is interfering with the system's ability to properly process shipping parameters.

Is it the theme?

v2.4.3

Thanks.

Comment: Hard to know if it is the theme, but try to change your theme for luma and check if you still have your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved. The site developer had implemented a custom module restricting the cart to UPS if the cart value was over a certain amount. That module has been disabled and the standard "Free Shipping" behavior is restored.